# How to import nested json into google big query

Tags: json, google-bigquery

I'm inserting JSON into Google Big Query.
At the bottom of the question is the schema of the JSON.

Below is an example JSON:

```
{
    "_index":"data",
    "_type":"collection_v1",
    "_id":"548d035f23r8987b768a5e60",
    "_score":1,
    "_source":{
        "fullName":"Mike Smith",
        "networks":[
            {
                "id":[
                    "12923449"
                ],
                "network":"facebook",
                "link":"https://www.facebook.com/127654449"
            }
        ],
        "sex":{
            "network":"facebook",
            "value":"male"
        },
        "interests":{

        },
        "score":1.045,
        "merged_by":"548f899444v5t4v45te9a4cc"
    }
}
```

as you can see there's a "_source.fullName" field with "Mike Smith".
When I try to create a table with it, it errors out:

> Array specified for non-repeated field: _source.fullName.

I believe this field is a one-time field for _source. How do I overcome this error?

here's the Schema:

```
[
    {
        "name": "_index",
        "type": "STRING",
        "mode": "NULLABLE"
    },
    {
        "name": "_id",
        "type": "STRING",
        "mode": "NULLABLE"
    },
    {
        "name": "_type",
        "type": "STRING",
        "mode": "NULLABLE"
    },
    {
        "name": "score",
        "type": "STRING",
        "mode": "NULLABLE"
    },
    {
        "name": "header",
        "type": "STRING",
        "mode": "NULLABLE"
    },
    {
        "name": "fullName",
        "type": "STRING",
        "mode": "NULLABLE"
    },
    {
        "name": "src",
        "type": "STRING",
        "mode": "NULLABLE"
    },
    {
        "name": "avatar",
        "type": "STRING",
        "mode": "NULLABLE"
    },
    {
        "name": "merged_by",
        "type": "STRING",
        "mode": "NULLABLE"
    },
    {
        "name": "cover",
        "type": "STRING",
        "mode": "NULLABLE"
    },
    {
        "name": "sex",
        "type": "RECORD",
        "mode": "NULLABLE",
        "fields": [
            {
                "name": "network",
                "type": "STRING",
                "mode": "NULLABLE"
            },
            {
                "name": "value",
                "type": "STRING",
                "mode": "NULLABLE"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "name": "_source",
        "type": "RECORD",
        "mode": "NULLABLE",
        "fields": [
            {
                "name": "fullName",
                "type": "STRING",
                "mode": "NULLABLE"
            },
            {
                "name": "links",
                "type": "STRING",
                "mode": "REPEATED"
            },
            {
                "name": "birthday",
                "type": "RECORD",
                "mode": "REPEATED",
                "fields": [
                    {
                        "name": "value",
                        "type": "STRING",
                        "mode": "NULLABLE"
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "network",
                        "type": "STRING",
                        "mode": "NULLABLE"
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "name": "phones",
                "type": "STRING",
                "mode": "REPEATED"
            },
            {
                "name": "pictures",
                "type": "RECORD",
                "mode": "REPEATED",
                "fields": [
                    {
                        "name": "url",
                        "type": "STRING",
                        "mode": "NULLABLE"
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "tab",
                        "type": "STRING",
                        "mode": "NULLABLE"
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "network",
                        "type": "STRING",
                        "mode": "NULLABLE"
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "name": "contacts",
                "type": "RECORD",
                "mode": "REPEATED",
                "fields": [
                    {
                        "name": "id",
                        "type": "STRING",
                        "mode": "NULLABLE"
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "fullName",
                        "type": "STRING",
                        "mode": "NULLABLE"
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "tag",
                        "type": "STRING",
                        "mode": "NULLABLE"
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "network",
                        "type": "STRING",
                        "mode": "NULLABLE"
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "name": "groups",
                "type": "RECORD",
                "mode": "REPEATED",
                "fields": [
                    {
                        "name": "id",
                        "type": "STRING",
                        "mode": "NULLABLE"
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "Name",
                        "type": "STRING",
                        "mode": "NULLABLE"
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "network",
                        "type": "STRING",
                        "mode": "NULLABLE"
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "name": "skills",
                "type": "RECORD",
                "mode": "REPEATED",
                "fields": [
                    {
                        "name": "value",
                        "type": "STRING",
                        "mode": "NULLABLE"
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "network",
                        "type": "STRING",
                        "mode": "NULLABLE"
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "name": "relations",
                "type": "RECORD",
                "mode": "REPEATED",
                "fields": [
                    {
                        "name": "value",
                        "type": "STRING",
                        "mode": "NULLABLE"
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "network",
                        "type": "STRING",
                        "mode": "NULLABLE"
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "name": "about",
                "type": "RECORD",
                "mode": "REPEATED",
                "fields": [
                    {
                        "name": "value",
                        "type": "STRING",
                        "mode": "NULLABLE"
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "network",
                        "type": "STRING",
                        "mode": "NULLABLE"
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "name": "emails",
                "type": "STRING",
                "mode": "REPEATED"
            },
            {
                "name": "languages",
                "type": "STRING",
                "mode": "REPEATED"
            },
            {
                "name": "places",
                "type": "RECORD",
                "mode": "REPEATED",
                "fields": [
                    {
                        "name": "network",
                        "type": "STRING",
                        "mode": "NULLABLE"
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "value",
                        "type": "STRING",
                        "mode": "NULLABLE"
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "type",
                        "type": "STRING",
                        "mode": "NULLABLE"
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "name": "education",
                "type": "RECORD",
                "mode": "REPEATED",
                "fields": [
                    {
                        "name": "network",
                        "type": "STRING",
                        "mode": "NULLABLE"
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "school",
                        "type": "STRING",
                        "mode": "NULLABLE"
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "name": "experience",
                "type": "RECORD",
                "mode": "REPEATED",
                "fields": [
                    {
                        "name": "network",
                        "type": "STRING",
                        "mode": "NULLABLE"
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "start",
                        "type": "NUMERIC",
                        "mode": "NULLABLE"
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "company",
                        "type": "STRING",
                        "mode": "NULLABLE"
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "title",
                        "type": "STRING",
                        "mode": "NULLABLE"
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "name": "networks",
                "type": "RECORD",
                "mode": "REPEATED",
                "fields": [
                    {
                        "name": "network",
                        "type": "STRING",
                        "mode": "NULLABLE"
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "link",
                        "type": "STRING",
                        "mode": "NULLABLE"
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "id",
                        "type": "STRING",
                        "mode": "REPEATED"
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "name": "network",
                "type": "RECORD",
                "mode": "REPEATED",
                "fields": [
                    {
                        "name": "others",
                        "type": "RECORD",
                        "mode": "REPEATED",
                        "fields": [
                            {
                                "name": "network",
                                "type": "STRING",
                                "mode": "NULLABLE"
                            },
                            {
                                "name": "value",
                                "type": "STRING",
                                "mode": "NULLABLE"
                            },
                            {
                                "name": "tag",
                                "type": "STRING",
                                "mode": "NULLABLE"
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "books",
                        "type": "RECORD",
                        "mode": "REPEATED",
                        "fields": [
                            {
                                "name": "network",
                                "type": "STRING",
                                "mode": "NULLABLE"
                            },
                            {
                                "name": "value",
                                "type": "STRING",
                                "mode": "NULLABLE"
                            },
                            {
                                "name": "tag",
                                "type": "STRING",
                                "mode": "NULLABLE"
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "music",
                        "type": "RECORD",
                        "mode": "REPEATED",
                        "fields": [
                            {
                                "name": "network",
                                "type": "STRING",
                                "mode": "NULLABLE"
                            },
                            {
                                "name": "value",
                                "type": "STRING",
                                "mode": "NULLABLE"
                            },
                            {
                                "name": "tag",
                                "type": "STRING",
                                "mode": "NULLABLE"
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "games",
                        "type": "RECORD",
                        "mode": "REPEATED",
                        "fields": [
                            {
                                "name": "network",
                                "type": "STRING",
                                "mode": "NULLABLE"
                            },
                            {
                                "name": "value",
                                "type": "STRING",
                                "mode": "NULLABLE"
                            },
                            {
                                "name": "tag",
                                "type": "STRING",
                                "mode": "NULLABLE"
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "spotify",
                        "type": "RECORD",
                        "mode": "REPEATED",
                        "fields": [
                            {
                                "name": "network",
                                "type": "STRING",
                                "mode": "NULLABLE"
                            },
                            {
                                "name": "value",
                                "type": "STRING",
                                "mode": "NULLABLE"
                            },
                            {
                                "name": "tag",
                                "type": "STRING",
                                "mode": "NULLABLE"
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Comment: Wondering first: Is this already a newline delimited JSON, and you posted it here pretty printed for readability?

Comment: yes sir.  one json per one line.  I just pretty printed it just for this.

Answer (score 1):

You could import the full json row as if it was a CSV - basically a one column BigQuery table of json objects. Then you can parse the JSON at will inside BigQuery, with queries like this:

```
WITH j AS (

SELECT """{"_index":"data","_type":"collection_v1","_id":"548d035f23r8987b768a5e60","_score":1,"_source":{"fullName":"Mike Smith","networks":[{"id":["12923449"],"network":"facebook","link":"https://www.facebook.com/127654449"}],"sex":{"network":"facebook","value":"male"},"interests":{},"score":1.045,"merged_by":"548f899444v5t4v45te9a4cc"}}""" j
)


SELECT index
  , STRUCT(
   JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR(source, '$.fullName') AS fullName
   , [
       STRUCT(
       JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR(source, '$.networks[0].id[0]') AS id
       , JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR(source, '$.networks[0].network') AS network
       , JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR(source, '$.networks[0].link') AS link)
     ] AS networks
   ) source
FROM (
  SELECT JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR(j.j, '$._index') index
    , JSON_EXTRACT(j.j, '$._source') source
  FROM j
)
```

[image]

See:

- https://medium.com/google-cloud/bigquery-lazy-data-loading-ddl-dml-partitions-and-half-a-trillion-wikipedia-pageviews-cd3eacd657b6

Comment: Great thought, but the file is too large to import as CSV.  it errors out.

Comment: `Array specified for non-repeated field: _source.fullName. `

Comment: You get that error when you load as JSON. What errors does it give you when you load as CSV?

Comment: file too big.  trying to cut it now

Comment: How can you get that error with CSV and not JSON? Both have the same limits https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/quotas#load_jobs

Comment: I don't know.  it worked once.  but the field was not there.  so I'm trying to put the field in.